# R arrange within function on multiple variables not using tripple dot

Tags: r

I would like to create an R function that besides many other things, arranges a dataframe on a vector of variables. Also being able to use the desc helper function. I have seen many examples using only a single variable, or the tripple dot argument. But I can't find a working example meeting all these conditions.

I tried the following (and many variations using enexprs/{{}}/eval_tidy), but I can't get it to work:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

dummy_df <- tibble(a = c(1, 1, 2), b = c("bac", "abc", "cba"))

arrange_df <- function(data, sort_vars) {
  sort_expr <- enquos(sort_vars)

  data <- data %>%
    arrange(!!!sort_expr)
  
  return(data)
}

arrange_df(dummy_df, sort_vars = c(desc(a), b))

# should be the same as:
dummy_df |> 
  arrange(desc(a), b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot recommend doing this without using the ellipsis. But if you really don't want to use it, then below is one approach (see comments in code).

The downside is, if the expressions are wrapped in anything else apart from `c()` or `list()` this won't work (for example `rlang::list2()`). To overcome this you could force the users to wrap even simple expressions, like just `a`, into `list(a)` or `c(a)`, but that is not really user-friendly.

I assume that you want to use the ellipsis for some other functionality. Maybe it is easier to first try to implement that functionality with just one input argument.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

dummy_df <- tibble(a = c(1, 1, 2), b = c("bac", "abc", "cba"))

arrange_df <- function(data, sort_vars) {
  
  # capture the expression without its environment
  sort_expr <- enexpr(sort_vars)

  # wrap in c() if not wrapped in list() or c()
  if (! deparse(sort_expr[[1]]) %in% c("list", "c")) {
    # we literally evaluate `sort_expr` and capture it again wrapped in `c()`
    sort_expr <- expr(c(!! sort_expr))
  }
  
  # turn every element into an expression and delete the first expression, c() or list()
  expr_ls <- as.list(sort_expr)[-1]
  
  # arrange the data
  arrange(data, !!! expr_ls)
  
}


arrange_df(dummy_df, desc(a))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>       a b    
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     2 cba  
#> 2     1 bac  
#> 3     1 abc

arrange_df(dummy_df, c(desc(a), b))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>       a b    
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     2 cba  
#> 2     1 abc  
#> 3     1 bac

arrange_df(dummy_df, c(a, b))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 2
#>       a b    
#>   <dbl> <chr>
#> 1     1 abc  
#> 2     1 bac  
#> 3     2 cba
```

<sup>Created on 2023-06-22 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot, this helped me to get it working. I have a question about the lapply step, where every element is turned into an expression. Is it really needed, or would a as.list() work aswell. Because every element is already an expression, or do I miss something? You do however need the 'split into several elements' part of the lapply, which as.list also can do. Thanks again for the quick response!

Comment: @TjarkvandeMerwe: Yes true, we don't need the `lapply()` and can just use `as.list()`. Nice spot! I adjusted the code accordingly.